# how to update multiple playlist items position at once using youtube api?

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I like to sort and update youtube playlist items by my own criteria but the problem is that I couldn't get my head around how to update the whole playlist items position at once.

As request body required data in the following format:

```
    body = {
      "snippet": {
        "playlistId": "PLyR_eqaLz2hmBPeDYO3pyXaqexCIV-PGp",
        "resourceId": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "fc6ZQX46Kz8"
        },
        "position": 3
      },
      "id": "UEx5Ul9lcWFMejJobUJQZURZTzNweVhhcWV4Q0lWLVBHcC41MjE1MkI0OTQ2QzJGNzNG"
    }
```

The problem with that format is that I can only request to updated single video in each request. A single request cost around 50 units of quota and is also slow. So, not suitable to apply this to a fairly large playlist.

Can anyone please help on how can I request multiple items in a single body or if anyone has already updated multiple items in a single body request please do share your code? Whether it is for youtube API or for any other app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation you will notice that [PlaylistItems: update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/update)

> Modifies a playlist item. For example, you could update the item's position in the playlist.

It updates a singular playlist item.  You can not update more then one.

Most of the Google apis do support batching but this is not going to help you as batching still uses the same amount of quota as sending the request singular.  I cant find any documentation though that says that the YouTube Data api even supports batching.

Your best bet is to go with what you are doing now and request additional quota if you need it.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to update multiple items in the playlist at once. If you would notice, its behavior follows the insertion sort algorithm where inserting an item would cause all others to move, depending on where the item will be inserted. The same behavior applies to update and delete.

For example, if you insert an item in the first position, all items in the playlist will move backwards.